# Using a different page number footer in the introduction

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I'm using roman page numbers in my introduction section, but for the remainder of the document I use arabic numbers, and this custom footer:

```
\cfoot{\normalsize{\thepage~/~\pageref{LastPage}}}
```

This leads to ugliness like:

```
i/16
```

in the introduction.

How can I specify a different footer for the introduction?

Comment: At the appropriate place inside your document you can issue `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}` (for arabic numbering) and `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}` (for Roman numbering), and your footer should follow suit. So, use the former at the start of your introduction and the latter at the start of whatever follows the introduction.

Comment: @Werner, I'm using `\pagenumbering{roman}` to switch the `\thepage` command between roman and arabic, and that works fine: the problem is the rest of the footer --- in the introduction I don't want the  `/ N` part of my `3 / N` page numbering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can issue a renewed `\cfoot` as needed to change the footer of the `fancy` page style. Here's a minimal example showing its usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage{lastpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\begin{document}

\cfoot{\normalsize\thepage}% Show only page number in footer
\pagenumbering{roman}% Roman-numbered pages (start from i)
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-15]

\clearpage
\cfoot{\normalsize\thepage~/~\pageref{LastPage}}% Show page / LastPage in footer
\pagenumbering{arabic}% Arabic-numbered pages (start from 1)
\section{Other sections}
\lipsum[16-30]
\end{document}
```

Renewing the footer (or header for that matter) will have an effect from "this page onward." That's why I issued `\clearpage` to restart the numbering and footer formatting on a fresh page. I assume you're doing the same.